# Echarts.js : How to create a custom chart type?

Tags: javascript, charts, baidu, echarts

I'm working with ECharts (http://echarts.baidu.com/index.html) for a few weeks, and I find this library very powerful.

However, it would be great if I could create custom chart types, e.g. a word cloud such as http://www.wordle.net/ (I've found a "character cloud" with echarts 2, but I'm not happy with it).

Is there an "easy" way to declare such a new chart type ? (otherwise I'll dig in the source files on GitHub).

Idealy, I would like to use the Echarts "engine" to provide nice features like export or data view, and implement only the "custom" parts (such as series declaration and rendering).

Thanks a lot, and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `extension` in ECharts. We are working on the documentation and demo to make extensions. Currently, you may refer to [the example of ECharts extension with Baidu Map](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/tree/master/extension).

Comment: Any news regarding the documentation and demo to make extensions?

I've found a few example on GitHub (https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/tree/master/extension/bmap, https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-graph-modularity, https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-wordcloud), but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @Ovilia year 2019. Any news on documentation? @Romain, have you managed to do something with a custom type of graph? The best I could find is to find a reference about type called `custom`, where you could implement a custom method of `renderItem` . The functionality is quite limited and is not the same as creating an extension of a new type.

Comment: @Ovilia please don't take my comment as an offense. Even with all this poor documentation and limitations - echarts is still my favorite library. It outperforms some other libraries such as Plotly.js as well as WinForms solutions, in my scenarios. I am grateful for the that work you do, but wish that you had explained better how the library could be extended. My need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694093/baidus-echarts-filling-up-space-between-2-lines